# Insert object containing objects in AWS DynamoDB using API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I'm using the Amazon API Gateway to request and put element on my DynamoDB (also from amazon). I already know how to insert simple object to one of my table but I can not figure out how to insert object which contains another object.

and this is how I'm trying to add this to my dynamodb:

```
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I have to do ?
I don't have any error but my object is not insering to y dynomoDB.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use an 'M' type for the nested object, but I'm not 100% sure (I'm from API Gateway team).

See API reference for DDB http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html#DDB-Type-AttributeValue-M

Comment: Thanks @Jack for your answer, I think you're right but I can not figure out how to write it...